# Multiple Nested query issue, possible to do it in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I asked a question earlier on today regards to  [Running multiple queries in loop, and building multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25327949/1214024) This code that I wrote works, but it just doesn't feel right.

The main issue I was noticing is that to do what I needed to do involved nesting queries inside the loop over of the results of a previous query. This seemed to kick up a stink of errors once I did this more than once, and after a little google time it seems that this just isn't possible to do. So I broke the queries apart and used a for loop for the second query. But this just feels messy, I'm now running two loops and I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this. Some code:

```
// get all to be done by each user
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT activityId FROM done WHERE userId=? ORDER BY number DESC");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $idq);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($aiddo);
$stmt->store_result();
$num_do = $stmt->num_rows;
  while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $activityId_do[] = $aiddo;
  }

// get location information
for($i=0; $i<=$num_do; $i++) {
  $act_done = $conn->prepare("SELECT fullAddress FROM `activity` WHERE (id=?)");
  $act_done->bind_param("s",$activityId_do[$i]);
  $act_done->execute();
  $act_done->bind_result($fullAddress);
    while($act_done->fetch()) {
      $do_array[] = array(
        "fullAddress"=>$fullAddress,
        "type"=>"do"
      );

    }
}
```

So this code above is inside a while loop over the results on a query that gets all the users a user is following.

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this, is it possible to use some kind of sql magic on it and do it all in the query?

Comment: General rule: if your inner queries depend on results on from outer queries, then they almost always can/should be re-written as a single JOINed query.

Comment: Whilst join is certainly the correct answer, you could reduce your current queries down to two by removing the loop and using `"SELECT fullAddress FROM activity WHERE id IN(".implode(',',$activityId_do).")"`

Comment: I run a similar query as above 3 times, each to get results to do, done and stories. These are all done inside the loop of a query that gets each user and user is following. Based on what you said would I need to still do each separately, but join not just these two but the query that gets the users a user is following too. So join, query that gets ids of users being followed with the query that gets the activity id's from done and the query that gets the address from activity. Then do this each time for do, done and story? Hope this makes sense, the full code is visible on the above link.